# Smart Pointer isn't smart enough

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Here is an example:

```
template<typename T>
struct smart { //Smart Pointer class
    smart();
    ~smart();
    smart(const smart& copy);
    T* target;
    int count;
};

struct atest {
    smart<atest> next;
};

void Garbage() {
    smart_ptr<atest> Test=smart<atest>(new atest);
//Test.count == 1
    Test->next=Test;
//Test.count == 2
//Test.target == Test->next.target
}
//Test.count == 1
//Test'll never be deleted! because it contains itself.

int main() {
    for (int i=0;i<10000000;i++) {
        Garbage();
    }
}
```

There is a resolve for this to make `Test` delete himself after `Garbage` method end?
And here is another question ,there is another holes in Smart Pointers?

Comment: What is `smart`? (that's probably the reason for the downvotes; this question is quite meaningless since no one knows what `smart` is) Anyway, if you use `new` to create smart pointers, you're simply fighting against the whole idea. You need to use RAII for this to work.

Comment: your login speaks to itself, messy code

Comment: `smart(const smart* copy);` should be `smart(const smart& copy);`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes This was a pseudo code. smart was smart pointer. the new before the smart pointer was a mistake.

Comment: @MessyCode That's not helpful. It's hard to provide decent help if you don't even bother describing your problem accurately. "Ah, this is not exactly my problem, but I want you to to solve my problem instead of this one" is a -1 from me.

Comment: even without `new` the line is wrong, why constructing a temporary object for assignment?

Comment: *your* smart pointer isn't smart enough. Did you try `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: Yes, the resolution is called a *weak reference*. You are doing something silly in storing a *strong reference* to itself - of course it will not clean itself up. A *weak reference* will not prevent cleanup. If you want to see real examples, look at `boost::shared_ptr`, and `boost::weak_ptr`. (NOTE: I've used Java terminology here, but the concept is the same)

Comment: Where's all the hate coming from? It seems quite clear to me that the question is asking how to resolve circular dependencies when using smart pointers, and the code is readable enough even if it does contain a couple of mistakes.

Comment: @Nim If in runtime I'll do it in mistake. Or not himself ,X contains Y Z contains X. They'll not ever deleted.

Comment: @MessyCode, don't get your point. If you do it by mistake, a memory leak will highlight that there is an issue, and then you'll debug and understand where the problem is, and there you will apply a weak reference. If you write the above relationship, you implicitly know what has to hold a strong reference and what has to hold a weak reference. You need to *think* about what you are doing here...

Comment: @Nim Then I can do it without mistake in developing game. There is a `Game` class and `GameObject` class. Game class has list of `GameObject` and all of those `GameObject`s has `Game` to do some stuff. Then if you throw away the `Game` and moves to another `Game` class ,like menu or gameplay. The list of `GameObject` and it's objects'll never get delete.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very vague, but I think it is about cyclic references, you should use, "weak" smart pointers in order avoid such. You can read more about how to break cycles using weak_ptr [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8394/Smart-Pointers-to-boost-your-code#Using%20weak_ptr%20to%20break%20cycles).

Comment: Note that weak pointers can only break *static* cycles.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - what is this concept "static cycles"?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I'm not sure what "dynamic/non-static" cycles are.

Comment: Cycles that are known at compile time are static. Cycles that can only be known at runtime are dynamic.

Comment: Isn't there an ultimate smart pointer? That I don't need to choose whatever I need?

Comment: @MessyCode there's no substitute for thinking.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: As long as you know which nodes could be part of a cycle, using a weak ptrs for them, you can also break cycles that my or may not exist at runtime.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I want to create interpreter with GC. I need one type for all.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Even though funny, your comment is not really true: the core of programming is building abstractions that allow one to think at higher and higher levels (and thus stop thinking about lower level concerns). In the case of memory management, garbage collectors allow you to (almost) completely ignore all aspects related to memory management and object ownership (whether this is a good thing or not is a different question...).